# SQL - given a date where something happened, get all consecutive days/records where the same thing happened

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite on a Windows Phone UWP app, but I guess this question would be equally valid on any SQL database:

I'm only looking for the SQL to achieve this - I can plug it into the code myself.

I have a Trip object:

```
public class Trip
{
    public string Iso3Code { get; set; }
    public string CityCode { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool DeletedTrip { get; set; }
}
```

When a user adds a trip, a `Trip` object is created for each day of the trip, e.g. user adds a trip to France from 1st April - 5th April. The system creates 5 `Trip` objects, one for each day.

I have an issue where, given a `Date`, `Iso3Code` (country code), `StateCode` and `CityCode`, I need to get all the `Trip` objects out of the SQLite database. e.g. for the trip example above, let's say I had the date 2017-04-03, I need an efficient way of retrieving all 5 `Trip` objects from the database.

My current method works, but for long trips, e.g. 2 years, it is EXTREMELY slow - I'm basically hitting the database once per day for the duration of the trip:

```
internal static List<Trip> GetWholeTrip(Trip trip)
{
    List<Trip> wholeTrip = new List<Trip>();

    Trip currentTrip = trip;
    //get trips before this date
    while (currentTrip != null)
    {
        wholeTrip.Insert(0, currentTrip);
        currentTrip = GetAllTripsOnDate(currentTrip.Date.Date.AddDays(-1)).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Iso3Code == trip.Iso3Code && p.StateCode == trip.StateCode && p.CityCode == trip.CityCode && !p.DeletedTrip);//Note: RMc - should only ever be 1 but using FirstOrDefault as we don't control the TT web service!
    }

    //get trips after this date
    currentTrip = GetAllTripsOnDate(trip.Date.Date.AddDays(1)).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Iso3Code == trip.Iso3Code && p.StateCode == trip.StateCode && p.CityCode == trip.CityCode && !p.DeletedTrip);//Note: RMc - should only ever be 1 but using FirstOrDefault as we don't control the TT web service!
    while (currentTrip != null)
    {
        wholeTrip.Add(currentTrip);
        currentTrip = GetAllTripsOnDate(currentTrip.Date.Date.AddDays(1)).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Iso3Code == trip.Iso3Code && p.StateCode == trip.StateCode && p.CityCode == trip.CityCode && !p.DeletedTrip);//Note: RMc - should only ever be 1 but using FirstOrDefault as we don't control the TT web service!
    }

    return wholeTrip;
}
```

So I basically loop backwards from the provided date, until I get to a day where there is no trip to the specified location, then I return to the provided date and loop forwards to a day where there is no trip to the specified location. This gives me all the consecutive days trips to that location.

Is there a SQL statement I could use to return the required data? - either in one hit, or - anything less than above would be good.

Comment: Don't list all the different databases in your tags, just use the tag for the database you're actually using.

Comment: Fair enough - I assumed some people would disregard if they didn't work with SQLite

Comment: Yes, they will. But it still shows up in their searches, which is annoying.

Comment: Why don't you have two objects, `Trip` and `TripDay`?

Comment: Please create a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve For SQLite it would be a `.dump` with `CREATE TABLE` and several `INSERT INTO`, to provide something to play with. Then define some desired outputs. I am not sure what language your question contains. Is it OK to provide only an SQLite query with desired info? I.e. not embed it in your code and only test in SQLite commandline?

Comment: As CL suggested it would make more sense to add to your current setup some information about the whole trip. You could, for example, add a generated id to all the trip days of a trip to identify them later. If you're using sqlite version 3.8 or above you could use a SELECT with a WITH clause. I've played around with an example here(https://gist.github.com/luksprog/53109c81ac9c724319881b0eebd9c28d), keep in mind that you might not get any performance improvements at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Creating a Trip object may create more problems than it solves, people can delete days, if they delete a day in the middle then I'd need to create two Trip, if they add that day back in, then we'd need to merge 2 Trips into 1. It's doable but adds complexity.